# Clang, LLVM, and g++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang, llvm

I installed clang to compare its use with g++ (gcc) for some C++ programs; as in, I compared compilation time, error feedback, etc,. for the same programs. I did this mainly for the official LLVM tutorial (implementing a compiler using LLVM).

At one point, I needed to install the LLVM libraries (v. 2.9.), while before I had only downloaded clang. Subsequent to this, compilation with clang++ doesn't seem to work for the following tutorial code; while g++ appears to work with LLVM directives (e.g., 'llvm-config --libs`, etc.). Concurrent to installation of the libraries, I had to also go from the old tutorial I was reading (llvm 2.2., suggesting clang++ syntax), to one for 3.0. (suggesting g++ syntax), as the library include locations had changed.

*My questions* to explain the changes after downloading the llvm libs:

(1) When I now type 'g++', am I still actually working with gcc, or has llvm/clang set itself as a new default mimicking the gcc syntax? If yes, how can I make sure that I actually use gcc, not clang, when I want to?

(2) If g++ still is gcc, any opinions/guesses why the official clang/llvm tutorial switches from suggesting the use of its own competing compiler back to gcc? (c., eg, [here](http://llvm.org/releases/2.9/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html))

My System:

Ubuntu 12.04.
llvm 2.9.
gcc 4.6.3.
clang 3.0.

Comment: Can you try running the commands `which g++` and `g++ --version`

Comment: As far as I know clang does not do anything with existing gcc executables. The LLVM tutorial you linked could use any C++ compiler so I'm guessing they switched to gcc because your average person is more likely to have gcc than they are to have clang.

Comment: @vonbrand: I typed 'llvm' in the software manager. Developer libraries popped, which I installed. Where I can arrange for it, I prefer to integrate my installs in the software mgr.

Comment: @Andrew.punnett: will do in the morning when back at comp.

Comment: It would also be helpful to run `ls -l $(which g++)` if you get the chance.

Comment: LLVM 2.9 is almost 3 years old. With the rate of changes LLVM goes through, there's no reason in the world to use such an ancient version

Comment: It's not aliased, and confirming with which etc, it still points to gcc.

Comment: It would be better to split the question in two questions. You should be more specific in the title. It is still worth to do it in 2019, because as you see: Readers get here and can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for typing `g++` to execute a clang compiler, you'd probably be looking at either a symbolic link called `g++` to clang, earlier in your `$PATH` than the path to the real `g++`, or else an alias named `g++`, along the lines of `alias g++='clang++'`.

You can check for the alias (although I imagine it's unlikely) by typing `alias g++`, which will let you know if you have any alias set up (and if so, what to)

In order to change the `$PATH` issue, if it occurs, you'd have to either remove the symbolic link (seems sensible, given if you wanted `clang`, you could just type `clang++` instead of `g++`) or change the position of the symbolic link in the `PATH` variable, but since they're likely to exist in `/usr/local/bin` or something similar, that would render a symbolic link unlikely too!

Given this, probably `g++` still calls the `gcc g++` compiler, and someone was just a little careless when typing the tutorial - I see only the one mention of `g++` on the page you linked, near the bottom?

Comment: Good suggestions, will check tom.

Comment: Last paragraph: it's more than that though. If you try the same command with clang++ replacing g++, you get errors galore. I assume that's not surprising as, maybe, llvm-config is meant to allow gcc to execute llvm code and libraries, and so wouldn't make sense with clang?

Comment: The bit I'm looking at reads `g++ -g -O3 toy.cpp \`llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core\` -o toy` - my understanding here is that the command that is enclosed within the `\`\`` marks will be executed by the shell, and then g++ will be executed - for example you can try `g++ \`echo "-I$DIR_TO_INCLUDE"\` file.cpp -o EXE_FILE` and it will include your directory. I can't really imagine why the output of `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core` should pass things accepted as flags by g++ but not clang++? Unless there's some slight syntax difference etc.

Comment: As in, to clear up the stupid way I wrote that - run the `llvm-config` command separately, and then check the stdout to see what it gives you, and work out if one of those is a valid flag for `g++` but not `clang` or `clang++`

Comment: It executes to a gcc (g++) style lib-include directive (-I/usr/lib/llvm-2.9./include), which at should clarify that this is either really targeting gcc, or at least that clang would be using the exact same options. I don't think it does though. And with clang, it does compile into terriblness (I tried yesterday). Probably, @David Brown nailed it: they might use gcc in more recent tutorials to focus on promoting llvm libs as a compiler-build tool, while de-emphasizing pushing their competing compiler clang at the same time.